# Android sd card default folders purpose

Tags: sd-card

I wonder what is the purposes of each of these extra folders that android creates on a sd card.

**Edit:**

.android_secure

.data

.estrongs

.showme

_nero_sync

Alarms

Albums

Android

DCIM

download

LOST.DIR

media

Movies

Music

My Documents

Notifications

OTA-Updater

Pictures

Podcasts

ppy_cross

Ringtones

Comment: Once you've found out: Please let us know. If you cannot find out, it might help to name the ones you're interested in ;)

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if we knew the names of the folders in question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of special Android SD card folders?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1658/list-of-special-android-sd-card-folders)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each app on your phone with the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission may create files or folders there. Most of these folders have once been created by one of these apps and many of them may be deleted with a few exceptions (e.g. Android, .data, .android_secure, these contain important system or app data like a game's downloaded content). Alas, it's impossible to tell exactly which folder belongs to which app.

- .android_secure: apps installed and then moved to sdcard
- Android: app data/cache
- data: app data
- .estrongs: ES file manager
- LOST.DIR: sort of trash folder (collects recovered files after phone crashes)
- DCIM: phone gallery's photos and previews
- OTA-update: [Over The Air update service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.otaupdater)
- ppy_cross: an unknown third-party app's data. [info](http://theselectedtechnews.blogspot.it/2012/09/android-users-facing-ppycross-folder.html)

I think you know what's in the others :)

Generally, note that uninstalling an app doesn't clean up the stuff it has created there. One needs to manually do this task but don't delete stuff if you're in doubt what it is.