# Should a new microSD card appear to have folders in Android?

Tags: sd-card, storage, reformat

We have a new Moto G8 Power and a new Samsung microSD card. I put the card in and turned the new phone on. When I looked in the file browser app it shows Samsung SD Card and that there’s 13 MB used, and then it lists “FILES ON SAMSUNG SD CARD” including folders of .android_secure, Android, Download, Music, Pictures, Ringtones, Alarms, DCIM, Movies, Notifications, and Podcasts.

The folders appear to be empty. Is this normal? I don’t have much experience with Android phones (I’ve been in the Apple ecosystem pretty much exclusively); Is this expected behavior, or should I reformat the microSD card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list you have provided is that of standard directories (see [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#fields_1) and [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/core/java/android/os/Environment.java#587)). Android OS creates these directories in external storage filesystems (including SD cards) when they are first mounted (see [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java#720)). As of Android 10 it includes 9 directories: **Alarms**, **DCIM**, **Download**, **Movies**, **Music**, **Notifications**, **Pictures**, **Podcasts** and **Ringtones**.

Android's *MediaScanner* service puts the files in these directories in special categories as the names suggest. See some more details in the related question suggested by @[Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy) in comment: [List of special Android SD card folders?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1658)

`Android` and `.android_secure` are exceptions though. `Android` directory contains apps' private directories in external shared storage (see details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526)). `.android_secure` is used by Android to move apps from internal to external storage (see details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221485/218526)).

So all of these folders are created by Android OS on first usage.