# How to stop automatic copying to usb flashdrive

Tags: folders, flashdrive, pendrive, copying

I have a OnePlus Nord N20 running android 11. Whenever I plug a flashdrive in, It dumps a bunch of empty folders onto the flashdrive. Alarms, Android, Audiobooks, DCIM, Documents etc. Does anyone know how to get it to stop doing that. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should a new microSD card appear to have folders in Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232062/should-a-new-microsd-card-appear-to-have-folders-in-android)

Comment: Related: [How to stop apps writing to "Android" folder on the SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526)

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion help me understand how the folders are getting there but not how to stop it from happening.